# Alternatives to a 'results' variable in recursive procedures

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, fold

Functions maintaining 'global' state for an inner recursive procedure which return multiple values (typically an array) are very common in a wide variety of problems in traversing graphs, string problems and software generally.

The function `permutations` and variable `results` below is one such instance of this "pattern". `results` exists in the scope of the inner recursive procedure `driver` but persists after the any call to `driver` has finished so that it may ultimately be manipulated / returned /
passed-to-callback.

```
function permutations(items) {
    var results = [];

    const driver = (members, idx) => {
        if (idx === members.length - 1) {
            // We have our desired result
            results.push(members.slice());
        } else {
            for(let i = idx; i < members.length; i++) {
                swap(members, idx, i);
                driver(members, idx + 1);
                swap(members, i, idx);
            }
        }
    }

    driver(items, 0);
    return results;
}
```

These sorts of procedures can occassionally be transformed into a series of recursive statements which are chained with `concat`. They might also be transformed into a number of applications of `map` / `reduce`.

I suspect this pattern has generated a body of literature in computer science and industry about the relative merits, performance details and theory behind these and other methods. What are they?

Comment: You might be interested in the paper [Functional programming with bananas, lenses, envelopes and barbed wire](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf), which discusses many generalizations of folds and other recursive patterns. It doesn’t really discuss performance, but that’s generally a highly complex topic that depends more on the semantics of your programming language (and its compiler) than any abstract algorithm can determine. Computational complexity is often identical, but performance characteristics can vary widely in practice.